# RequiredJS failed to Load a JS file

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require

I have this simple example in RequiredJS and tried to load the jQuery file but throws an error. What am I doing wrong?

**Hierarchy**

```
index.html
scripts/
        libs/
             jquery.js

        compute/
```

**config.js**

```
requirejs.config({

        baseUrl: 'scripts/libs'
    });


    requirejs(['jquery'],
    function(sub) {
        console.log(sub);
    });
```

> SCRIPT5022: Script error for "jquery"
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js (7,175)

Comment: shouldn't `requirejs(['jquery'],` be `require(['jquery'],` ?

Comment: @AdityaParab Nope

Comment: @Nick Have you followed the instructions in: https://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html ?

Comment: @David Yes   i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below works for me:

```
requirejs.config({
    // Path mappings for the logical module names
    paths: (function () {
        var pathObj = {};
        pathObj = {         
            'jquery': '../your/path/to/js/libs/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min'          
        };        
        return pathObj;
    })(),   

    // Shim configurations for modules that do not expose AMD
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: ['jQuery', '$']
        }
    }    
});
require(['jquery'],
        function ($) {
             $.ajax({/*some ajax call for example */});
        }
    );
```